# Converting Excel documents to PDF using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, pdf, dll

I have set of excel documents in a folder and I need to convert them to PDF programatically. I have tried microsoft's export as fixed format using interop.excel dll,but unfortunately I do not have office installed in my server system,so it is working in my local, but it is not working on server.Is there any third party free ware dll through which I can convert excel documents to pdf which do not need any installation on server system.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Vamsi

Answer (score 0):

I suspect any third party pdf .dll would need Microsoft Office installed on the server. We  had a similar problem and after much research had to resort to installing excel on an application server to handle the requests.